# How to crack sparsebundle Time Machine backup?

Tags: backup, time-machine, sparsebundle

I hope someone could help me.

I've forgot the Time Machine disk password, and I need it to restore backup to my new iMac.

Searching on the web I read about John the Ripper, it could help me.
I've installed it, but now I need to place the command into Terminal app to recover the password.

Could someone write the code for me?

Comment: See [How long would it take to crack AES-128 knowing a 12 character length password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173910/how-long-would-it-take-to-crack-aes-128-knowing-a-12-character-length-password)

Comment: You may have already checked this, but just in case: If you use iCloud keychain syncing, and the password was stored to your keychain, you might be able to find it in the Keychain Access app on your new Mac. It should be named by the backup drive's name.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but I hadn't enabled password storage in the keychain. The only solution is brutal force